# Improving cache hit rate

Tags: c, caching, cpu-architecture

Hey so I have a function written in `c` whose cache performance I have to improve. The statistics are being provided by `cachegrind`. But I'm completely stuck and cannot get more than 10% improvement in the performance. I really need help with this.

Here is the function:

```
#define LARGER  50000

typedef struct { 
    char c1;
    double f1;
    int n1; 
    char c2;
    int n2;
    double f2; 
} data; 

char* func()
{
    data* B = (data*) calloc(LARGER, sizeof(data));
    if (!B) return 0;

    double sum_f = 0.0;
    double sum_n = 0;
    char* sum_c = (char*) malloc(( 2 * LARGER + 1) * sizeof(char));

    sum_c[2 * LARGER] = '\0';

    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < LARGER; i++)
    {
        sum_f += B[i].f1 + B[i].f2;
        sum_n += B[i].n1 + B[i].n2;
        sum_c[2 * i] = B[i].c1;
        sum_c[2 * i + 1] = B[i].c2;
    }

    free(B);
    return sum_c;
}
```

The first thing that I noticed is that the definition of the `struct data` is not very cache-friendly because it has a ton of padding.

So, I changed the definition according to allignment requiirements to this -

```
typedef struct {
    int n1;
    int n2;
    double f1;
    double f2;
    char c1;
    char c2;
} data_new;
```

But this gives me only around 10% increase in cache-performance. I have no ideas on how to modify the for loop to improve the spatial locality further.

Can anyone guide me on how to be able to write better loops that are cache-friendly.

P.S. I am doing these questions as a part of my self study of a computer architecture book and I have no instructor to seek help.

Comment: We are no code-review site. **Read the FAQ** of code review, **iff** your code is correct, it might be a candidate for them. But you should provide definitively more information, there are a lot of very different CPUs on the market.

Comment: @Olaf will /proc/cpuinfo help? Also I'm not expecting cpu specific answers. Just general guidelines on how to improve cache-performance of such loops.

Comment: Not here and not enough. Sorry, still too broad. Please understand.

Comment: Okay. Will repost on codereview.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because review of functional code is off-topic for Stack Overflow. Your question may be on-topic for [codereview.se].

Comment: @AneeshDandime: To emphasise: **check their FAQ before posting**!

Comment: You can try playing with builtin_perfetch, but the HW prefetcher is probably taking care of that already. Still, you can manually check various distances ahead.

Answer (score 1):

For the code posted; the CPU would read cache lines in ascending order and write cache lines in ascending order. There is no better (more cache friendly) access pattern than that (partially due to CPU's "hardware prefetcher").

The only other things you can do is to reduce the size of the data (but I can't see how).

There's also ways of improving the code (`clflush`, SIMD) that won't make any difference to cache miss rate.